# CSS: float:right not working properly

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I've an issue with IE on this website: ...

When you click on the article "Post Tenebras Luxe", you'll see that the big image is overlaying the artists list, instead of moving down.

How can I fix the css ?

thanks

Comment: May I suggest you cut down the number of `div` s you are using? They seem completely useless and make the page a nightmare to debug...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding a "clear: both;" on the fieldset containing the images (or inserting a "" before the image? That would appear to be your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the float i.e. after the div that has the class 'field-field-artists' insert an empty div like so:

```
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```